# node-redis: How does executeIsolated impact watched keys?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm trying to debug some `WatchErrors` in my project and am noticing that we aren't using an `isolatedClient` and am wondering if that is the cause. I don't see any logs (or code paths) that would indicate that the watched keys are being changed after being watched.

Here is basically what my code looks like when I actually write to Redis in a transaction:

```
try {
  await this.client.watch(key);
  await this.client
    .multi()
    .hSet(key, some_value)
    .expire(key, some_expiration)
    .exec();
}
catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof WatchError) {
    // seeing this block get hit often
  }

  throw e;
}
```

I noticed in the node-redis README that the [Transactions section](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/master#transactions-multiexec) gives an example without calling `.watch()` *without* creating an `isolatedClient`. However, in the linked example that [*does* call `.watch()`](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/isolated-execution.md), there is the additional creation of an `isolatedClient` with the `executeIsolated` method.

What exactly are the implications of using an `isolatedClient`? Do we need to use one of these if we are calling `.watch()` and if so, why? Will a `WatchError` be thrown if a different connection is used between `.watch()` and `.exec()`?

Answer (score 0):

`redis-server` stores the `WATCH` state on the connection, which means that concurrent `WATCH` and `MULTI`/`EXEC` will override the state for each other... in this scenario you'll need to have a pool of connections, and every time you need to `WATCH`, take a connection from the pool, and use it instead (which is exactly what `executeIsolated` is doing):

```js
client.executeIsolated(async isolatedClient => {
  await isolatedClient.watch(key);
  await isolatedClient
    .multi()
    .hSet(key, some_value)
    .expire(key, some_expiration)
    .exec();
});
```

you can configure the pool behavior by passing the `isolationPoolOptions`  option to `createClient`:

```js
createClient({
  isolationPoolOptions: {
    min: 1,
    max: 100
  }
});
```

see [generic-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generic-pool) for more options.